# How can I append a something from within the parent if it is not in the child?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using **Python 3.7**.

I have 15 similar div which is name ="parentclass", some of childs containing "specific-class" and some of childs dont have, i must appent to my_list[] if dont have "specific-class"

**What i want to do:**

```py
my_list = []

for i in range(1,16):
    check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("
.//div[not(contains(@class, "specific-class"))] and
./parent::div[@class, "parentclass"]")

    code = check.get_attribute("code")
    my_list.append(code)

print(my_list)
```

This should give me just (3/15) result as:

> **B00UXIHA0W , B00YHY6IFQ , B01IH34UMA**

But not working

**If I do**:

```py
my_list = []

for i in range(1,16):
    check = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='parentclass']["+str(i)+"]")
    code = check.get_attribute("code")
    my_list.append(code)

print(my_list)
```

This give me all parentclasses code (15/15) result as:

> B01N1UX8RW, B0761VJFWY , B01DG8DA22 , **B00UXIHA0W** , B00D8P5T0U , **B00YHY6IFQ**, B00NCUJCPE , **B01IH34UMA** , B01KWTGIBS , B00X6DVBGA , B07BHXY78B , B07DQWT15Y , B07HL5K4RM , B071CPQYD5 , B07MDB6PSD

And I dont want to like that.

My 1. div:

```
<div code="B01N1UX8RW" class="parentclass">
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">
            <div class="class3">..</div>
            <div class="class4">
                <div class="class5">
                    <div class="specific-class">
                       <span>text</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My 8. div:

```
<div code="B01IH34UMA" class="parentclass">
    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">
            <div class="class3">..</div>
            <div class="class4">
                <div class="class5">
                    <span>text</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XPath

```
//div[@class='parentclass'][not(.//div[@class='specific-class'])]
^ find a DIV that contains the class 'parentclass'
                           ^ but does not have a descendant DIV that contains the class 'specific-class'
```

Your code would end up looking something like

```
my_list = []

for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='parentclass'][not(.//div[@class='specific-class'])]"):
    my_list.append(element.get_attribute("code"))

print(my_list)
```